# Problem opening terminal in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, python, gnome-terminal

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 from scratch.

It comes with Python 3.8.5.

I needed Python 3.7.9 so I have installed it also using dead snakes repository.

When I have restarted the pc I couldn't launch the terminal.

I have checked gnome-terminal file and it points to `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Please advise what is wrong with the setup? Why it happens, please explain with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by installing KDE and choosing it as my display manager.

Here is how:

1. Use tasksel command to install KDE plasma desktop.
   In case the tasksel command is not available on your system you can install it by running `sudo apt install tasksel`
2. Run `sudo tasksel install kubuntu-desktop` or `sudo tasksel install kubuntu-full` to begin the KDE Plasma desktop installation.
3. When finished installation choose `sddm` as your display manager right after the installation finished or run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`
4. Choose the `sddm` and reboot the system.

Hope it will help others.